# TypeError: Deno.run is not a function

Tags: deno, deno-deploy

My project works perfectly fine locally, but when I deploy the project on `deno.dev` it crashes.

```
TypeError: Deno.run is not a function
    at build (file:///src/scripts/build.ts:2:26)
    at file:///src/server/main.ts:3:7
```

When my project runs for the first time, I attempt to create a sub process, using `Deno.run`

Is `run`from the Deno API not available on deno deploy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Deno.run` is not available on Deno deploy. You can see all available APIs in the following link:

- https://deno.com/deploy/docs/runtime-api

Aside from `Deno.run` there are several APIs not currently available, including **all** unstable APIs.

---

From Deno deploy issues: https://github.com/denoland/deploy_feedback/issues/288

> It is our intention that all stable APIs in Deno will exist in Deno
> Deploy too, in the limit. A user calling Deno.run() on Deno Deploy and
> receiving an error such as PermissionDenied: running subprocesses is
> not permitted in this context has a much better experience than a user
> that receives: TypeError: undefined is not a function (calling
> Deno.run).

Comment: Thanks for the response, so I'm guessing that `Deno.run` is unstable or do they not want users to be able to run a sub process?

Comment: The latter. `Deno.run` is a stable API